# Spring batch - Worker step execution context not aligned with the context in the database

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have implemented remote partitioning with a manager step processing 2 files in two workers.

The last step of the job (manager) is a tasklet that loops over the jobExecution.stepExecutions() and looks for the write/read count of a specific step name.

The issue I am having is that while in the BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION table persisted in the db (mysql) the worker steps have the context aligned to what I expect, the context pulled from the object in the java code is empty (read/write count is 0) , I have also tried to add these value to the stepExecutionContext but still the context contains only the partition key with the file path.

This is my worker step

```
@Bean
public Step mainWorkerStep() {
    return this.remotePartitioningWorkerStepBuilderFactory
            .get(STEP_NAME_MAIN_WORKER)
            .inputChannel(requests())
            .listener(switchDataSourceListener)
            .<IntegrityReport, IntegrityReport>chunk(integrityJobPropertyHolder.getStagingWriterChunkSize())
            .reader(integrityReportReaderConfig)
            .writer(integrityReportWriterConfig)
            .listener(partitionImportSummaryListener)
            .build();
}
```

and this is the manager step

```
@Bean
public Step loadDataManagerStep() {
    return remotePartitioningManagerStepBuilderFactory
            .get(STEP_NAME_LOAD_DATA_MANAGER)
            .partitioner(STEP_NAME_MAIN_WORKER, batchCommonMultiResourcePartitioner)
            .gridSize(10)
            .timeout(30 * 60 * 1000) // 30 minutes
            .pollInterval(10000) // 10 seconds
            .outputChannel(outboundRequests())
            .build();
}
```

As you can see from the screenshot below the status is STARTING while in the db is COMPLETED.

[image: step execution memory context]

[image: database context]

Comment: Is that last tasklet a separate step coming after the partitioned step? How do you get the job execution?

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine last tasklet "ImportSummary" is where I get the stepExecution info , chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().getJobExecution().getStepExecutions() . I also tried to add the info from the worker to the job execution context but the new entries are not persisted into the db. I have extended the BatchIntegrationConfiguration to set a specific txManager I am wondering if that could be the problem

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine.  public class IntegrityBatchIntegrationConfiguration extends BatchIntegrationConfiguration {
    public IntegrityBatchIntegrationConfiguration(JobRepository jobRepository,
                                                  JobExplorer jobExplorer,
                                                  @Qualifier("batchJobManagementTxManager")
                                                  PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
        super(jobRepository, jobExplorer, transactionManager);
    }

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine I removed the BatchIntegrationConfiguration extension and I am now pulling the write/read count information from the loadDataManagerStep where they are set correctly, not sure why though the partiion:0/parition:1 step execution contexts are not updated when pulling the info from the tasklet

Comment: Do you have a minimal example I can use to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine not right now, but I will try to push something to github and share it with you, thanks !